# Pipe separator shown on new line in bootstrap nav

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a boostrap nav with dropdowns.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
  <li>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <a data-target="#" data-toggle="dropdown">User <span class="caret"></span></a>

      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="account?open">Rediger konto</a></li>
        <li><a href="orders?open">Vis ordre</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
  ....
```

Between the menu entries I want to add pipes.

```
#options-nav .nav>li:after {
  content: "|";
  ...
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/casperskovgaard/eww51eo3/

Problem is that the pipe for the dropdown entry is shown on a new line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The div inside the list item is the cause of the issue.

Because of its `display: block` style it is pushing down the `after` pseudo-element.

Add a `display: inline-block` to the div alongside the after pseudo-element:

```
#options-nav .nav>li>div {
    display: inline-block;
}
```